# How do I remove the X buttons in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, browser

I went to my profile settings and added a folder called 'chrome' and a file called `userChrome.css`.

I included this code:

```
@namespace url("http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul"); /* only needed once */

#tabbrowser-tabs .tabbrowser-tab .tab-close-button { display:none!important; }
```

I restarted my Firefox instance and it still shows the X close button in the tabs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> **Note**: Firefox 69 and new versions will not support **userChrome.css** and **userContent.css** by default unless preference is set by the user.

To use **userChrome.css** follow below steps:

- First type `about:config` in url/address bar
- Then search for the property named `toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets`
- Set it to `True` and restart firefox

Comment: Thanks! Noting that it doesn't work on the active tab

Comment: Yep! Looking for an answer that covers that

Answer (score 3):

another solution ( use `.tabClipWidth` )  from here
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1247072

// NOTE: this solution only hide **other tabs** close btn,
current tab's close button can't hidden.
// no need of CSS

1. Enter `about:config` in your Firefox address bar
   Bypass the warning message
2. Find the `browser.tabs.tabClipWidth`
   Change the value to a large number (for example, 1000000)
3. Apply by Restart Firefox

// 2022-10 still works @firefox 103

Comment: This solution is much easier and quicker to do. Just set the tabClipWidth to a bigger value (for example 280 instead of the default 140) and you're done - no tab close buttons are shown, except for the active tab. It is easy to revert to - just search for tabClipWidth in about:config and use the reset arrow, to revert your changes.